# Failed to clean a folder in afterStep in Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a job where I process and copy all files from a dir to another dir.**After the step** I want to delete the first directory but I get an error while trying to delete the last file processed(copied).The result is a folder with only **one** file that can't be deleted and this file happens to be the last processed
My StepExecutionListener looks like this:

```
public class CleanUpListener implements StepExecutionListener {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CleanUpListener.class);

private String folderToBeDeleted;

@Override
public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution arg0) {
    try {
        logger.info("Deleting folder: " + folderToBeDeleted + " ...");
        File file = new File(folderToBeDeleted);
        logger.info("folder contains: " + file.listFiles().length);
        FileUtils.deleteDirectory(file);
        logger.info("Deleted folder: " + folderToBeDeleted);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Failed to delete folder: " + folderToBeDeleted + " with exception: " + e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void beforeStep(StepExecution arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public String getFolderToBeDeleted() {
    return folderToBeDeleted;
}

public void setFolderToBeDeleted(String folderToBeDeleted) {
    this.folderToBeDeleted = folderToBeDeleted;
}
```

}

produces a result:

```
11/03/2014 13:53:56.804 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] [] INFO                 CleanUpListener - Line (29) Deleting folder: C:/Myfolder ...
11/03/2014 13:53:56.806 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] [] INFO                 CleanUpListener - Line (31) folder contains: 14
11/03/2014 13:53:56.826 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] [] ERROR                CleanUpListener - Line (35) Failed to delete folder: C:/Myfolder with exception: java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file: C:/Myfolder/14.xml
```

**All files are deleted except the last one processed**(14.xml)

**UPDATE:**
Reader of the step:

```
<bean id="modelReader"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader"
        scope="step">
        <property name="resources" value="file:${step3.reader.resource}/*.xml"></property>
        <property name="delegate" ref="staxPatentReader"></property>
        <property name="strict" value="true"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="staxPatentReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader">
        <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="Root" />
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="modelMarshaller" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="modelMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="classesToBeBound">
            <list>
                <value>com.sample.MyModel</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: In Windows you can not delete file which is being opened by some process. So you should check that you don't have this file opened in any editor or whether your batch application itself didn't forget to release the file handle.

Comment: This file is not open anywhere except the spring batch process.The thing is that it's the last xml processed in the ItemReader so I guess that the lock is not released when afterstep is called but that's really weird.

Comment: Oh God, then only in another step as @bellabax suggested. Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: Just checked the source code of `AbstractStep#execute`. `StepExecutionListener#afterStep` is called before `ItemStream#close` so your approach is doomed to fail :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To this kind of step use a custom [Tasklet](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/step/tasklet/Tasklet.html) implementation.

```
class DeleteFilesTasklet implements Tasklet {
  execute(StepContribution, ChunkContext) throws Exception {
    // do deletion and return the right value
  }
}
```

and in your job.xml

```
<job>// previous steps
  <step id="deleteFiles">
    <tasklet ref="deleteFiles" />
  </step>
  <bean class="DeleteFilesTasklet" id="deleteFiles" />
</job>
```

In this way you are sure all files (and other resources) has been closed in the previous step.

Comment: That's my second choice ;).It's not possible to clean the folder in the same step?

Comment: maybe. but use the same stap give you a real gain in terms of maintenance? separation? or performance?

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci I moved the file cleanup into another step, but still no luck. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68149680/java-nio-file-filesystemexception-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it

Answer (score -2):

You can do delete via JobExecutionListener.